# How does answering a call from the bridge in Star Trek work?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-discovery

When an officer is summoned to the bridge, or the captain is called to the bridge, is the communication through the [Console](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Console)? Or is it through the ship's computer?

How does the person receive the communication? And how do they answer?

In Star Trek Enterprise they press a button to reply.
In Star Trek The Next Generation they touch their badge.
In Star Trek Discovery they simply talk without any physical contact with the ship.

Is there a link that explains the evolution of communication in the ship through the different series?

P.S. Sorry for the bad wording. I am still learning how to write coherently.

Comment: This seems like a dupe of this https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55156/why-is-there-no-combadge-lag-on-initiating-inter-personnel-comms aside from the part where you've noticed that Star Trek Discovery is a great big pile of anachronisms

Comment: @Valorum should I delete my question?

Comment: Up to you. There's a list of discrepancies here that you could (potentially) add to; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/172890/in-universe-explanation-for-why-is-the-tos-era-enterprise-is-more-austere-than-t

Comment: @Valorum I hope by 'discrepancies' you mean 'variance' [in a good sense]. I doubt my ability in understanding the language with all it's nuances. If so, i'll leave the question for a day or two.

Comment: Actually I mean *"stuff that they completely mucked up because they don't give a hoot about continuity or pleasing their long-term fanbase."*

Comment: @Valorum Very true. It is getting very confusing for us fans who even without the scientific background understand the blunders that they have made.

Comment: Have you *seen* how badly current IT Companies manage to mess up the User Interface and User Experience in the name of "progress"?  (And then have to roll it back)  I just assume that someone decided to get rid of the "press button to talk" feature in a software update, and that at some point in the next 10 years it will cause sufficient inconvenience to enough (or *important* enough) people that the functionality is rolled back.  (I'm sure you can think of embarrassing moments to receive a phone call when someone might be saying "yes" for unrelated reasons...)

Comment: In a very basic way, the link is based on real ships at sea.  When Roddenberry made the original Trek, the thinking is that it would be like real ships, where the call goes out over the ship and the captain finds an intercom to press a button and respond. By STTNG, wireless tech had progressed a lot and so did assumptions about future tech.  But in Discovery, it is based more on modern stylistic choices that you would see in, for example, the Mission Impossible movies. And of course, as @Valorum points out, they don't care about continuity anymore, just squeezing the money stone.