# Does Michael Burnham exist in the Kelvin timeline?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery, star-trek-2009

I'm not asking [if Discovery exists in the prime or Kelvin timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171095/is-star-trek-discovery-set-in-the-original-or-the-kelvin-timeline), I'm asking if a Burnham counterpart exists in the Kelvin timeline, and does she go into the Kelvin timeline version of the future?

Out of universe, Star Trek: Discovery was 10 years away, so the idea of Spock having a sister wasn't incorporated in [Star Trek (2009)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0796366/).

Comment: but a definitive (er...believable) answer as to whether or not Disco is in Kelvin-verse or not is crucial. Production staff insists it's Prime universe, even though it makes no sense though :\

Comment: Do we actually know if Discovery is in the Prime or the Kelvin universe? For all we know it could be in a 3rd universe

Comment: @NKCampbell - A Discovery equivalent might exist, but that's not the ship we're seeing in the show. According to the production staff, we're in the prime universe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Her existence in the Kelvin timeline hasn't been confirmed in canon. We have [official confirmation](https://twitter.com/DavidAlanMack/status/908544616860762112) that, despite the overwhelming number of inconsistencies, that Discovery exists within the same "Prime" timeline in which TOS, TNG, DS9 and VOY exist.

> *"Discovery is in the Prime timeline. It fits w/canon"*

It's likely that she exists (since the timelines are very similar) but there's no proof positive either way.

Answer (score 7):

I haven't tracked down the exact scene, but [multiple](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5870994/trivia) [secondary](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/2226) sources claim that Michael was born in 2226, and that this was revealed in "The Butcher's Knife Cares Not For The Lamb's Cry."

The initial scene of *Star Trek (2009)* where the timeline splits occurs in 2233. So Michael would already have been seven years old.

That is, unless the timeline split has retroactive effects, Michael must exist in the Kelvin timeline. There's no guarantee that her history after the age of seven is anything like it is in the prime timeline, though.

Comment: The timeline split does indeed have retroactive effects.

Comment: Exact dates aside, season 2 of *Star Trek: Discovery*, with the relationship between Spock and Michael being a major factor of the entire season, makes it clear that Michael was noticeably older than Spock when Sarek adopted her and they first met, and Spock's birth was the same year as *Kelvin* incident.

Comment: @Valorum According to what?

Comment: @BrianOrtiz - According to the guy what wrote it; *"Spock’s incursion from the Prime Universe created a multidimensional reality shift. The rift in space/time created an entirely new reality in all directions, top to bottom, from the Big Bang to the end of everything."* - http://simonpegg.net/2016/07/11/a-word-about-canon/

Comment: @Valorum He only wrote one film and it seems to be something he made up all by himself.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz - It was also stated by Robert Orci and appears in the ST: Encyclopedia (new edition).